# Formula for the expected return time for states of a continuous Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, stopping-times

given a continuous time Markov chain $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ with Q-Matrix $Q$ and countable state space $S$, is there a formula for calculating the expected first return time of a state i.e a formula for $E_z[R_z]$ where

$$
R_z := \inf(t> \tau_z : X_t = z) \quad\text{and}\quad \tau_z := \inf(s\geq 0 : X_s \neq z).
$$

If there is non such formula, is there a proof of concept how to show if $E_z[R_z]$ diverges or converges?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Assume state $z$ has steady state probability $p_z$. You can set up renewal frames that start when we return to state $z$. For renewal frame $k \in \{1,2,3,...\}$ let $S_k$ be the duration of time we stay in state $z$ until leaving, let $R_k$ be the time to return to state $z$, so frame $k$ has total size $S_k+R_k$, and by renewal-reward theory the fraction of time we are in state $z$ is (with prob 1) $p_z=\frac{E[S_1]}{E[S_1]+E[R_1]}$.  But $E[S_1]=1/v_z$ (where $v_z$ is the sum outgoing transition rates from $z$), and so $E[S_1]+E[R_1] = 1/(v_z p_z)$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "state z has steady state probability". $X_t$ is a continuous MC, therefore it will stay in state $z$ for $\exp(-q(z,z))$ time, right? Or do you mean $p_z := -q(z,z)$?

Comment: The notion of steady state is fundamental to Markov chains and theorems in that direction and about global balance equations (aka "stationary equations") are easy to find on the web.